# Generating even numbers >100 starting from 10 to n

Tags: bash

This 100 is count not the max even number.
Here is my current code:

```sh
INDEX=10
while [ $INDEX < 200 ]
do
    REMAINDER=$(( $INDEX % 2 ))
    if [ $REMAINDER -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo $INDEX
    fi
    INDEX=$(($INDEX+2))
done
```

Comment: Use `-lt` instead of `<`.

Comment: Btw., you can achieve the same result by doing `seq 10 2 200`.

Comment: You DON'T NEED to SHOUT.  You can use lower case identifiers.  Indeed, doing so is preferred.

Comment: Redirection operators can appear in any order in a simple command, so `[ $index < 200 ]` is the same as `[ $index ] < 200`.  This does not do numerical comparison.

Comment: `printf "%s\n" {10..100..2}` would do the job at once. `seq` or a looping construct isn't needed.

Answer (score 1):

When you just want to generate numbers, you can use

```
for ((i=10; i<100;i+=2)); do
    echo "i=$i"
done
```

When you do not want to use your knowlegde of increasing with 2, you can loop and check with

```
for ((i=10; i<100;i++)); do
    if ((i%2==0)); then
       echo "i=$i"
    fi
done
```

And when you like oneliners, you might use

```
printf "%s\n" {10..100..2}
```

Comment: and if i want binary search then how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

`seq` can solve this task directly for you:

```
seq 10 2 100
```

Comment: Just `seq 10 2 100`, the loop is useless... Please do not use \` backticks - use `$(...)` instead. The `for i in $(command)` is a common __anti__ - pattern, you should not use it. Instead use `while IFS= read -r`. see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: While poorly presented as first answered, this question offers valuable insight: `seq` will do the trick. Answer edited to keep that nugget.